# How should I make the date command use the same format as rdiff-backup?

Tags: command-line, bash, date, timestamp, rdiff-backup

The `rdiff-backup` command creates incremental backups by creating several files with datestamps in their titles. The datestamps are of the format defined in the [W3 Note about datetime](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime), which are essentially:

> Complete date plus hours, minutes and seconds:
>
> YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)

Where the T in the middle is a literal 'T' to denote that the time starts at this point.

I'd like to be able to mirror this format using the `date` command. So far I have:

```
date '+%FT%T%:z'
```

Which works brilliantly if I'm in any timezone other than GMT/UTC, giving the output in the expected format.

When in the GMT/UTC timezone, the timezone string at the end should be output as the letter `Z` rather than the current `+00:00`.

I'm sure I could do this by obtaining the timezone part with a separate `date` command and changing it if it matches +00:00, or by using some sort of parameter expansion if I save the string as a variable, or maybe even using `tr`. Is there a direct way within the `date` command options, if not how should I achieve this simply?

Comment: Does `date --iso-8601=seconds` do it for you? It looks about right for my locale/TZ on 16.04

Comment: @steeldriver I'd totally missed the timespec options, though it still outputs the timezone as `+0000` when in GMT. Thanks for drawing my attention to it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think GNU date has any option for printing `Z` instead of the UTC timezone. It's easy enough with `sed`:

```
$ date '+%FT%T%:z'       
2017-01-24T14:06:39+00:00
$ date '+%FT%T%:z' | sed 's/+00:00$/Z/'                            
2017-01-24T14:07:52Z
```

Comment: This'll be the best way to do it I think, it seems odd that there's no option to use Zulu time in GNU date.